# how do I use launch.json with arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code

error message:
preprocess.py: error: the following arguments are required: --dataset_type, --output_format, --label_map_path, --input_dir

my launch.json is formatted:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["--output_format tfrecord",
                     "--dataset_type superannotate",
                     "--project_name Production_BB_batch9",
                     "--input_dir /home/evan/Datasets/SA_batch13_OBJ_DET9",
                     "--label_map_path /home/evan/Datasets/SA_batch13_OBJ_DET9/label_map.pbtxt"
                    ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you try splitting arguments? ie. `["--output_format", "tfrecord", ...]`

Comment: no luck but thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

The debug button is currently bugged. If debugging is launched from the command palette or with shortcut F5 debugging with arguments works as expected.
-note: arguments in a single string should be given with an = instead of space (i.e. "--myarg=10")